# Emacs can not access its own manual

Tags: help, info, manual

I just installed Emacs 25.2 on my computer, but I can not access its manual. when I press `C-h r` this screen [image] opens which lacks any links related to the Emacs manual. Futhermore, the echo area displays the message `Info file emacs does not exist`. How do I debug and/or fix this?

Comment: This sounds like the Emacs manual files were not installed in the correct location. How did you install Emacs 25.2? Which OS are you running?

Comment: I installed it through apt-get install. My OS is Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Have you installed the `emacs25-common-non-dfsg` package? Its descriptions reads `GNU Emacs common non-DFSG items, including the core documentation`.

Comment: Basil Thank You. This package has solved my problem. And now I'm able to access the manual. جزالك الله خيرا

Comment: وإياك, happy to help. :) In future please stick to English, though, in consideration of other users.